# How to Evaluate javascript using WKWebView in iOS Swift?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I trying to evaluate `javascript` from an `URL`. I have `iframe` which is loaded to `WKWebView`. Now I need to evaluate `javascript` from `iframe` and need the callback of `javascript` evaluation.

Please refer to what I have tried so far.

```
public func loadWebView() {
    if let formValue = formKey {
        print(formValue)
        var embededHTML = "<html><body><iframe id='formFrame' src=\"api url here/\(formValue)/index.html\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe></body>"
        embededHTML += "<script> var winpost = document.getElementById('formFrame').contentWindow;"
        embededHTML += "function sendFormData(a) {  console.log(a); retrun a; }"
        embededHTML += "</script>"
        embededHTML += "</html>"

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "base url here")
        self.webView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: url)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    }
}

public func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController,didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if(message.name == "callbackHandler") {
        print("JavaScript is sending a message \(message.body)")
    }
}


public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("function name() { return 23 };sendFormData('hihihihi')") { (result, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print(result!)
            print("Web View didFinish Loading");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can take a look at this post https://medium.com/@DrawandCode/how-to-communicate-with-iframes-inside-webview-2c9c86436edb